# How to access latest mail from a specific sender in outlook using python script

Tags: python, email, outlook

Using the following code, I am able to access the latest mail from outlook. But I want to access the latest mail from a particular sender.

```
import win32com.client

win32com

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

I have seen the following code to get the sender's address. But I am unable to get the latest mail from that address using `Getlast()`

```
for m in messages:
   if m.SenderEmailAddress == 'some_sender@somewhere.com':
       print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in a folder are not stored in any particular order until you call `Items.Sort`.
Sort the items by the `ReceivedTime` property, then use `Items.Find` to search on the `SenderEmailAddress` property.

Comment: The items in Inbox are already according to the received time. The latest one appears first.

Comment: What you see in the Inbox folder in Outlook has absolutely no relationship with what is returned from the MAPIFolder.Items property. You can just as easily sort your Inbox folder by the sender name. Or any other property. That won't change a thing when you access the items programmatically. If you don't call Sort, no particular order should ever be assumed. You might get the order in which the items were created (which is not the same as the received date), but no assumption must ever be made. Do call Sort.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me how to sort Inbox folder basing on the sender name or sender ID and get the latest mail from it.

Comment: Please see my answer above - sort by ReceivedTime  property, call Items.Find to find a message with the given SenderEmailAddress property.

Comment: I sorted based on ReceivedTime property. But I am unable to find latest message with the SenderEmailAddress from that sorted mails. There is chance that a mail from other sender would be present after the mail from the actual sender. I am able to read only the latest mail received but not the latest one from required sender.Can you please help with that.

Comment: messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
for msg in messages:
    if msg.SenderEmailAddress == "The sender email address":
        messages.Sort("[SenderEmailAddress]")
        message = messages.GetLast()
        body_content = message.body
        print body_content

Comment: messages = inbox.Items;  messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True) ;   msg = messages.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'user@domain.com' ")

Comment: From those messages, how can we access the latest one

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot and ended up with this.It won't able to use the sender address instead it uses the sender name.

`for m in messages:
   if m.SenderName == 'some_sender_name':
       print(m)`